# unable to execute linux command using paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I have written code which will login to remote server and execute below 2 command

> cd /path to folder/
>   rm -rf /myfolder/view1

```
class ssh:
client = None

def __init__(self, address, username, password):
    print("Connecting to server.")
    self.client = client.SSHClient()
    self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(client.AutoAddPolicy())
    self.client.connect(address, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False)

def sendCommand(self, command):
    if(self.client):
        stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command(command)
        while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
            # Print data when available
            if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
                alldata = stdout.channel.recv(1024)
                prevdata = b"1"
                while prevdata:
                    prevdata = stdout.channel.recv(1024)
                    alldata += prevdata

                print(str(alldata, "utf8"))
    else:
        print("Connection not opened.")
```

> connection = ssh(ipaddress, username, password)
>   connection.sendCommand("cd /path to folder/")
>   connection.sendCommand("rm -rf /myfolder/view1")

Folder is not deleted after doing this. Please help

Comment: If you didn't get an error then the cmd was run somewhere :D double check your parameters.

Comment: Do you have access to that directory with your user?

Comment: i fixed my problem after checking my parameters